# insert multiple rows in realm in swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm new in realm. I've below array in `viewcontroller`:-

```
var vatr = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

and I've an `Vatrom` class.

```
Class Vatrom:Object{
    dynamic var vatrom1:string= ""
}
```

now I need to insert that array element as an individual row. 
I'm not getting how'll I do this.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I catch your meaning, it can be written as follows:

```
var vatr = ["1","2","3","4"]

let realm = try Realm()

try! realm.write {
    for string in vatr {
        let vatrom = Vatrom()
        realm.add(vatrom)
    }
}
```

See https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/